# How can I do a RedirectToAction but as a POST instead of a GET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, redirecttoaction

We have a login method in a Authentication Controller that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateModelState]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    var certificateName = GetCertificate();
```

GetCertificate() looks like this:

```
public string GetCertificate()
{
    var headerCertificateValue = Request.Headers.Get("X-ARR-ClientCert");
    return headerCertificateValue;
```

Basically we are using a cert in a header for authentication.  So right now we are in the middle of trying to test that the cert header will work.

I have a form that looks like this to Mock our cert serving mechanism:

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("MockEcaCertLogin", "Authentication", new { area = "Login" }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h1 class="bg-info">Mock ECA Login</h1>
        <div class="margin-bottom-20 margin-top-20">

            @Html.DropDownList("CertName", new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "First Last", Value = "First.Last.M.CCCdddddddddd.ID" },
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "First Last", Value = "FirstLast" },
            })

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>

        </div>
    }
```

This posts here:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public RedirectToRouteResult MockEcaCertLogin(string certName)
{
    Request.Headers.Add("X-ARR-ClientCert", certName);
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

which should go back to the original Login method and the cert would be in the header ready for the authentication so we can test that it works.

The problem is that a RedirectToRouteResult cannot be a post.
How can I achieve this?  Does anyone know?

Comment: RedirectResult always issue a GET request.So you can not do Post with `RedirectToAction`

Comment: Why are you adding a header to the request and then abandoning it?  It seems like the attempt so far may have been based on a number of misconceptions.

Comment: Why not set  the header in client side and then submit the form using javascript, to the Login httppost action method ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateModelState]
        public void MockEcaCertLogin(string certName)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(this.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
            var destinationUrl = urlHelper.Action("Login", "Authentication");

            var headers = new NameValueCollection();
            headers.Add("X-ARR-ClientCert", certName);
            HttpContext.Server.TransferRequest(destinationUrl, true, "POST", headers);
        }
```